# Check if timer is finished

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm sandboxing a little timer app.
I'm using  [this cocoapod](https://github.com/suzuki-0000/CountdownLabel)

This is my code so far:

```
import UIKit
import CountdownLabel

class ViewController: UIViewController { 

    @IBOutlet weak var moreBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var lessBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var gifview: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var countdownLabel: CountdownLabel!
    var mins = 25
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupCountdown()
        updateTimer(min: mins)
    }
    
    // MARK: Buttons
    
    @IBAction func startPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        countdownLabel.start()
    }
    @IBAction func lessPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if(mins > 0){
        mins = mins - 5
        updateTimer(min: mins)
        }
    }
    @IBAction func morePressed(_ sender: Any) {
        mins = mins + 5
        updateTimer(min: mins)
    }
    
    
    
    //MARK: Helper Func
    
    func updateTimer(min: Int){
        countdownLabel.setCountDownTime(minutes: 60*Double(min))
    }
    
    func setupCountdown(){
        countdownLabel.textColor = .black
        countdownLabel.font = UIFont(name:"Courier", size:UIFont.labelFontSize)
        countdownLabel.animationType = .Evaporate
    }
}
```

Now I want to check if the timer is finished (can use this cocoapod built in function: countdownLabel.isFinished() ).

But I have no clue WHERE and HOW I can check this, e.g. in viewDidLoad() I can’t check .isFinished()....

As an example: if(countdownLabel.isFinished()){countdownLabel.text = "Finished"}
WHERE to insert this line in the code??

I would be very happy if you can quickly copy and paste the code as an answer - with the mentioned line correctly inserted :)

Thank you!

Comment: You'll save yourself some headache if you get into the habit of representing times _always_ as seconds using NSTimeInterval.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `delegate` method `countdownFinished()` of `CountdownLabel` to check when counter finished as mentioned in the example of this pod. Your updated code as below

```
import UIKit
import CountdownLabel

class ViewController: UIViewController { 

    @IBOutlet weak var moreBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var lessBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var gifview: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var countdownLabel: CountdownLabel!
    var mins = 25
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupCountdown()
        updateTimer(min: mins)
    }
    
    // MARK: Buttons
    
    @IBAction func startPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        countdownLabel.start()
    }
    @IBAction func lessPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if(mins > 0){
        mins = mins - 5
        updateTimer(min: mins)
        }
    }
    @IBAction func morePressed(_ sender: Any) {
        mins = mins + 5
        updateTimer(min: mins)
    }
    
    
    
    //MARK: Helper Func
    
    func updateTimer(min: Int){
        countdownLabel.setCountDownTime(minutes: 60*Double(min))
    }
    
    func setupCountdown(){
        countdownLabel.textColor = .black
        countdownLabel.font = UIFont(name:"Courier", size:UIFont.labelFontSize)
        countdownLabel.animationType = .Evaporate
        countdownLabel.countdownDelegate = self  //>>>>>> added this line to your code
    }
}

//>>>>>>added this function to your code
extension ViewController: CountdownLabelDelegate {
    func countdownFinished() {
        debugPrint("countdownFinished at delegate.")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a 'listener' for when it reaches 0 ("Finished")

From the docs (they only show on various times, though for 0 you should use

```
countdownLabel.then(0) { [unowned self] in
    countdownLabel.text = "Finished"
}
```